# Derivative of inverse at specific x value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I am having trouble with finding the derivative of an inverse function at a specific x value. I know these things:

$$f(x)=x^3-2$$

$$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2}$$

if

$$x=25$$

$$f^{-1}(25)=3$$

However, I am trying to find $f^{'}(f^{-1}(25))$ and getting nowhere.

I plug in 3 for the inverse function at 25 and all I get for the first step after this is $f^{'}(3)$ which is clearly not right. I am supposed to get $3(something)^2$ after the $f^{'}$ step and simplify and the online homework software is asking me to put in an exact number at every step. I assume that means that whatever I do, I shouldn't put some function of x as the answer to any of the steps. So I am stuck here. If I can't use the variable x in my answer, how am I going to find the derivative at that specific point where x=25?

Comment: $$(f^{-1}(25))'=\frac{1}{f'(3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about a few things, so I'll try to go go through them.

**Method to find Derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $x=25$**

If $f(x)=x^3-2$ then you're correct in saying $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2}$.

I'm going to ignore the $f'$ notation in favor of the derivative operator $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)$, to remove some confusion.

Using the chain rule, we find that the derivative of the inverse function is: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt[3]{x+2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x+2\right)^{1/3}=\frac{1}{3}\left(x+2\right)^{(1/3)-1}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x+2)=\frac{1}{3}\left(x+2\right)^{-2/3}$.

To find the derivative at a certain point, say $x=25$, you'd substitute $x=25$ into the equation and calculate $\frac{1}{3}\left(25+2\right)^{-2/3}$. When you simplify that number, it's the *"derivative of $f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=25$"*. Nothing else is required.

**Unecessary Step $1$: Computing $f^{-1}(x)$**

If you're given that $x=25$ then you don't need to plug $25$ into the inverse function. We're not interested in what $f^{-1}(x)$ is doing at $x=25$; we want to know what $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{-1}(x)$ is doing there. These are different things.

**Unecessary Step $2$: Computing $f'(f^{-1}(x))$**

This might just be a mistake in your notation but $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{-1}(x)$ is *not* the same thing as $f'(f^{-1}(x))$. The first formula, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{-1}(x)$, says that we're *differentiating* the inverse function. But the second formula, $f'(f^{-1}(x))$, says that we're plugging the inverse function into $f'(x)$, which is the derivative of the **ordinary** function not what we want (we want the derivative of the **inverse** function). Furthermore, you mention "$3\,\text{something}^2$" which is $f'(x)$ (not what we want).

---

I don't mean to discourage you by pointing out mistakes but its best to learn how to avoid them. Also, I'd initially answered the *wrong* question, since I'd misunderstood what you were asking. As **Raffaele** points out, there is a possible method you can use to find the answer, from the Inverse Function Theorem, with $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f^{-1}(x)\big|_{x=25}=\frac{1}{f'(x)}\big|_{x=f^{-1}(25)}$ but I think it'd be better for you to be more comfortable with the basics before using that.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$
f(x)=x^3 -2 
$
and 
$f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2}$,

so:

$f'(x)=3x^2$ and $\left(f^{-1}\right)'(x)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}}$

Frome the inverse function derivative formula we have:

$$
\left(f^{-1}\right)'(25)=\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}(25)\right)}
$$
so:
$$
\left(f^{-1}\right)'(25)=\frac{1}{f'(3)}=\frac{1}{27}
$$

and  deriving the inverse function we have the same result:
$$
\left(f^{-1}\right)'(25)=\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{27^2}}=\frac{1}{27}
$$

Comment: Right, but the first step I see in my homework after solving for $f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=25$ is $f{'}(f{-1}(25)) = f{'}(something)$ I don't see a $\frac{1}{f^{'}}$ in there. And it is asking me to put in an exact number. So how can I get this $1/f^{'}(3)$ to be just 1 single $f^{'}(something)$ and still get that 1/27 answer?

Comment: @Caters.  I'm not sure to understand what you wont, but, if you want  find $something=x$ such that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{27}$ you simply have to solve the equation $ 3x^2=\frac{1}{27}$, that gives  $x=\pm \frac{1}{9}$